# How to detect whether a link is hidden in a collapsed twitter bootstrap nav bar with jQuery or vanilla JS

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, overflow, hidden, nav

I am having an issue with detecting the visibility of a navigation link within a twitter bootstrap responsive navbar when it is in the collapsed state.

The root of the issue is that the .collapsed div has an overflow:hidden rule set to it. This means that although the navigation ul has non-zero dimensions, it is still hidden, because the .collapse container has zero height (set in style attribute in the closed state).

The problem is that if #some-nav-link is one of the li items in the .nav ul it would be matched by $('#some-nav-link :visible'), because it does not know that the element is hidden by the overflow.

Is there a fool proof way to check visibility of element that could account for this?

I tried relying on elementFromPoint using the li $.fn.offset() method, but it is not good enough in cases where the li would have some padding, for example, in which case the elementFromPoint return one of the parents of the li.

NOTE - My code is third-party code on the relevant website, so I cannot change anything in how the nav bar works.

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**
I am looking for a solution that is independent of the mechanics of how the twitter bootstrap collapse works. That is a general solution to the issue of determining the visibility of an element which is in the overflowing part of a child of an overflow:hidden element. I felt that it'd be better to tie this to the concrete problem which prompted this question, but if the current question will be deemed confusing I am open to revising it accordingly. I hope this update would be enough though.

Thanks for reading, I am looking forward to some clever solution!

Here is a fiddle showing the check for :visible returns true when collapsed-
http://jsfiddle.net/VDR3Y/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery implementation of the selector `:visible` requires both the **height** AND the **width** to be set to 0 in any ancestors in order to fail.  Otherwise your original code would have worked.

AFAIK there is no selector that will do this outright, so a custom function may be required:

```
(function () {

  function isCollapsed(element) {
    var $e = $(element);

    return $e.width()*$e.height() === 0;
  }

  $.fn.isReallyVisible = function () {
    var $this = $(this).filter(':visible');

    // if jQuery says its not visible, trust it, otherwise
    // check if any of the parents are collapsed
    return $this ? !$this.parents().toArray().some(isCollapsed) : false;
  };
})();
```

This will handle your cases where parents are collapsed.

```
$('#some-nav-link').isReallyVisible();
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/mUeay/)

You may need to add more to handle overflows, but since that wasn't in the OP, I figure this will work for now.

Comment: This seems to be just the thing! Thanks a lot, and also for the new fiddle. Not only did I learn how to solve my problem, but I also learned about Array.some() which I never ran into before. From what I read it is not implemented in oldIE, but that could easily be fixed.

Comment: I updatd your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mUeay/3/ to use .filter instead of .toArray().some, so I guess it should now be oldIE safe. thanks again!

Comment: @odedbd I learned about `Array.some()` from my experience with ActionScript. It's a super useful method, not only for it's efficiency, but moreover for it's semantic value.  Anyway, MDN has a patch for older IE versions in the [Compatibility section of the `Array.some()` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Compatibility). I'd recommend using that patch instead of `filter()`. Glad to help!

Comment: thanks for this update. Why do you recommend against using filter, assuming I am already using jQuery? The semantic value? Or is there some other important factor?
Since my code runs as a third-party code on other people's website, I don't think I can patch the array prototype as suggested by MDN.
Anyways, thanks for your great help and for following up on the comments like this. I appreciate it.

Comment: @odedbd My suggestion is mainly for performance reasons. Even though in theoretical terms `filter()` and `some()` are both **O(n)** algorithms, in *practical* terms `filter()` will *always* execute over every item, whereas, in collapsed cases, `some()` will only execute *until* a true case is found. If the element being check has many ancestors, then that practical difference represents a useful optimization. Another option which would nearly eliminate the difference would be to limit the parents to `parents('.collapse')`, or similarly narrow selector. However, that is not Bootstrap-agnostic.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

Put this Check

```
$('div.nav-collapse.in').length > 0 ? 'links are visible' : 'links are not visible'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it is of course to the point of my question. However, I now realize I did not state in my question that I am looking for a general solution not depended on bootstrap's implementation. This is my bad and I will fix it promptly in the question. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: You can do that with the 'hasClass' function.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested - I ended up going with a different solution, based on document.elementFromPoint.

```
(function($) {

    function checkFromPoint(index) {
        var $e = $(this);
        var fromPoint = document.elementFromPoint($e.offset().left + $e.width() / 2, $e.offset().top + $e.height() / 2);

        return $e.get(0) == fromPoint || $e.has(fromPoint).length;
    }

    $.fn.isReallyVisible = function() {
        var $this = $(this).filter(':visible');    

        return $this.length ? !!$this.filter(checkFromPoint).length : false;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

I updated a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxHmk/) where you can see it at work.